# How to pass data to embed ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a code, which must pass data with segue:

```
let navController : UINavigationController  = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
let viewController : UIViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! CTableViewController

viewController.SelectedTypeOfVariable = "G"
```

But I have the following error:

> UIViewController does not have a member named SelectedTypeOfVariable

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    let viewController : CTableViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! CTableViewController
    viewController.SelectedTypeOfVariable = "G"
```

I think the reason for this is because you are saying your "viewController" variable is of type UIViewController. If your "viewController" variable is of type UIViewController, then it indeed does not have a member named SelectedTypeOfVariable. Your subclass of UIViewController, "CTableViewController" does though and so you need to make sure your variable is of type "CTableViewController"

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
let viewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! CTableViewController
```